# Discrepancy between MATLAB and Simulink closed loop response?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a closed loop system which I am testing in MALTAB and Simulink, expecting the same output.

**MATLAB**

```
num_plant = [0.0001 10];
den_plant = [0.005 5 0.6616 61.01 2.11 20];
G1 = tf(num_plant, den_plant)

num_controller = [46615 6526 5.722e05 2.389e04 2.001e05]
den_controller = [1 404 41605 162000 200000]

C2 = tf(num_controller, den_controller)
G2=G1*C2; %G1 is same 5th order TF as Simulink
new2 = feedback(G2, 1);
step(new2)
```

Note:

```
G1 =

                       0.0001 s + 10
  --------------------------------------------------------
  0.005 s^5 + 5 s^4 + 0.6616 s^3 + 61.01 s^2 + 2.11 s + 20

C2 =

  46615 s^4 + 6526 s^3 + 572200 s^2 + 23890 s + 200100
  ----------------------------------------------------
     s^4 + 404 s^3 + 41605 s^2 + 162000 s + 200000
```

[image]

**SIMULINK**

[image]

---

According to the official documentation, [feedback](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/feedback.html) should be doing what I am presenting with blocks in Simulink. Surely I am missing something. I checked the code and everything should be the same in both cases. What is the reason for this discrepancy?

AS per JonRB's answer:

```
>> which step -all
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\toolbox\control\ctrlobsolete\step.m
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\toolbox\shared\controllib\engine\@DynamicSystem\step.m  % DynamicSystem method
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\toolbox\ident\ident\@iddata\step.m                      % iddata method
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\toolbox\matlab\system\@system\step.m                    % system method
```

Anything suspicious?

Comment: Well it looks like you just edited your question a few times to what I thought was wrong so I'm glad you were reading my mind. Anyways... Your time scale is radically different than your MATLAB plot and your Simulink plot? What if they were the same scale? I see a _tiny_ plateau on your Simulink plot that looks like your MATLAB plot.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that! Thanks for you contribution, you are right. I updated the question...  Still, however, the graphs don't look identical to me. Could there be something else which I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

I would say you are doing something wrong in using matlab

```
num_plant = [0.0001 10];
den_plant = [0.005 5 0.6616 61.01 2.11 20];
G1 = tf(num_plant, den_plant)

num_controller = [46615 6526 5.722e05 2.389e04 2.001e05]
den_controller = [1 404 41605 162000 200000]

C2 = tf(num_controller, den_controller)
G2=G1*C2; %G1 is same 5th order TF as Simulink
new2 = feedback(G2, 1);
step(new2,50)
grid
```

This produces:
[image]

And in simulink

[image]

All intent and purposes... identical.

[image]

In fact executing: **[y,t] = step(new2,50)** and playing back in Simulink shows this

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to try this out. Strange, I keep getting the original response in the question. Could it be that I'm using a different solver or something of the sort?

Comment: Maybe JonRB is using a later version.

Comment: I am using R2018b but the step command hasn't changed in over a decade. Looking at the stype of @Rrz0 simscape scopes, he is using at least R2016a. At this point I would delete the local user profile MATLAB settings directory to see if some single-precision option in matlab was enabled

Comment: I am on R2018a. WiIl look into this further. Thanks

Comment: I add a vote for numerical precision problems -- any sort of math involving polynomials has all kinds of problems with numerical precision that just gets worse as the order goes up.  Particularly if Matlab is making a 9th-order transfer function (as opposed to cascading two state-space models) then it would account for that much difference (in fact, I'm kinda surprised it works with double-precision).

Comment: Performed all the steps given https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/99625-how-do-i-regenerate-my-matlab-preferences](here) but I still get the same response.

Comment: I am starting to thing you have a shadow command somewhere... what is the output of: which step -all

Comment: Updated question to show output.